# matlab get color

Tags: matlab, graph

I am using matlab for cluster visualization. I want to somehow get the color of my current cluster center fill in the plot and draw line of same color to cluster members. How can I get the color?

Comment: More information needed to understand your problem. Please describe the problem in more details. If possible, add some visualization and/or your code examples?

Answer (score 6):

This is a generic answer to finding the color of any plot object in Matlab.

Select the object in the plot and use gco to get its color attribute.

```
c = get(gco,'Color');
```

Without any specific information about how and what you are plotting, it is not possible to give a more specific answer.